# Java adding natives to classpath

Tags: java, lwjgl

I have a pretty big game which uses A LOT of libs and I added them in the classpath, which works fine. But when I launch the program it says

> no lwjgl in java.library.path

This is easy to solve in Intellji idea but how can I add this in the classpath so that `lwjgl` knows where the natives are located?

Comment: Is this after exporting from Intellij?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch you jar using a batch file:

```
java -jar Game.jar -Djava.library.path="path_to_your_natives"
```

**Before** creating your Display, you have to call the following line:

```
System.load("name_of_dll");
```

Note, that you don't have to put `.dll` at the end. You can alternatively call

```
System.loadLibrary("path_to_dll");
```

. That way, you don't have to use a batch file. But you may not forget the extension.